# Is it possible to record sound in torch 7?

Tags: lua, audio-recording, audio-processing, torch

As title,

Is it possible to record sound in torch 7 ?

Is there a library to do this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it, but it seems doing what you look for.
https://github.com/ansca/Simple-Audio-Recorder/blob/master/main.lua